Why is it that all the examples i can find for WebSocket in C# have websocketHolder as a singleton?
Im trying to learn and understand on how to use websockets. And i have noticed that every tutorial and example i have seen have the holder class for websocket registred as a singleton.
Why doesent each connection have its own handler? I think that would make it more easier to handle concurrent data. for ex a chat application where multiple user send messages at the same time, or multiple parallel chatrooms, etc.
To me it seems like a bottleneck, that when server is accepting data from 1 client, all the other connections have to wait. Or am i mistaken?

In most WebSocket examples in C#, a singleton is used to manage connections to make things simpler and to have a central point for managing all connections. However, this doesn't mean that all connections have to wait for each other. WebSockets work concurrently, meaning when a message comes from one client, the server can process it without blocking the other connections. The use of a singleton is just for better and centralized management, not to cause delays or blocking of other connections.

So the methods in the holder can run concurrently?
